# Spy private method on thread with mockito

Tags: java, multithreading, mockito, powermock

I have a runnable that call a void private method during his lifetime.
I want to test, using PowerMockito, that my method "processStep" is really call only one time for each argument.

MyRunnable class

```
public class MyRunnable extends Runnable {
    MyRunnable(args){
    ...
    }

@Override
public final void run{
    ...
        processStep();
        ...
    }

private void processTep(a){
        ...
        addAttributeResult();
        ...
    }

private void addAttributeResult(){
    ...
    }
}
```

My test class for testing MyRunnable class

```
@PowerMockIgnore("org.apache.log4j.*")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DBReader.class, MyRunnable.class })
public class CycleManagerTest {
    @Test
    public void myTest(){
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable(arg[] {a,b});
        Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
        t.start();
        while (myRunnable.getNbrEndCycle() < 1) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        t.interrupt();
                    for(String s : arg){
                        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(myRunnable, times(1)).invoke("processStep", a);
                    }
    }
}
```

When there is only one argument the test succed but when there are many arguments, the test is on error like this :

```
*org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at fr.MyRunnable.addAttributeResult(MyRunnable.java:254)
Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()
Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.*
```

I really don't understand what happend. I think i am totally wrong somewhere.

Comment: What observable effects would there be if `processStep` got called twice?  Or if it didn't get called at all.  If there are none, then why do you care about testing it?  And if there _are_ observable effects, then surely you can test _those_.  Exactly how many times `processStep` gets called is an implementation detail that should not be part of a unit test.

Comment: There are some observable effects for some arguments, but not for all. I want to test if for each argument given, the method `processStep()` is really called, it is what i am trying to do here. By the way i am not sure that is a part of unit testing. Maybe just see the result of `MyRunnable` should be my unit test (if i understand you) ?

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should test _behaviour_, not _implementation_.  If an implementation detail has no effect on behaviour, then the net benefit of testing it will actually be negative.

Comment: Ok, i see what you are telling me. I have to be focus on the behaviour and not on the implemantation. I will try to keep it up in my mind.

Answer (score 2):

The `@PrepareForTest` annotation should refer to the class containing the private method to test, here `MyRunnable`. See the last sample of https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13.

Comment: Yes of course, i did it, just i failed my copy/paste here. It's `MyRunnable` that was refer on the `@PrepareForTest` annotation.  I edit my post to correct this.